# How do I determine type of "Login" in Windows 10 using .net?

Tags: .net, authentication, windows-10

Windows 10 has a feature under Sign-in Options called "Use my sign-in info to automatically finish setting up my device and reopen my apps after an update or restart" as mentioned it will automatically sign-in.

I found a way to disable the setting through Registry, but I don't want to use this solution.

I want to know whether user logged in manually (and thus the startup programs ran) or its the Windows auto-login that started the startup programs.

I am trying this identification from my .net application (startup app).

---

i have used ' My.Application.GetEnvironmentVariable("username") ' to get the logged in username , How do i go about getting the type of login ?

Comment: i have used ' My.Application.GetEnvironmentVariable("username") ' to get the logged in username , How do i get the type of login ? also why is this not the right place?

Comment: Okay, its right type of question if its for .net application. Please share your code you tried in your question as well. I'm sure somebody will help you.